# Adding methods to class template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, stl, template-specialization

I would like to achieve behaviour present in STL: when we look at a vector container, it is known that it has `vector<bool>` specialization which adds method `flip()`.

Is it possible to achieve such class extension without copying the whole class as a specialization and adding new method in its body?

Comment: You can use inheritance from stl::vector

Comment: No, no - i want to extend my own class, the `vector<bool>` was just an example. My class has nothing to do with vectors, but i would like to have different methods depending on type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can SFINAE the method of "specialization"

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    // Common code...

    template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<bool, U>::value, bool> = false>
    void only_for_bool() {/*..*/}
};
```

C++20 would allow better syntax:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    // Common code...

    void only_for_bool() requires (std::is_same<bool, T>::value) {/*..*/}
};
```

Comment: I have a question through: 
is the `template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<bool, U>::value, bool> = false>` 

somehow not equivalent to:
`template<typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<bool,T>::value>>`  ? 

Why is there a need for doing the `typename U = T` and the last `= false` bit?

Comment: for SFINAE, method should be template. class is not enough, and so you would have hard error instead of **S**ubstitution **F**ailure.

Comment: `typename = std::enable_if_t<cond>` can be hijacked `only_for_bool<int, void>`, no allow other overload with complementary condition (if you want different version for `int` and `bool`) (as default template isn't part of signature). `std::enable_if_t<cond, bool> = false` allows complementary condition, cannot be hijacked (condition should also check that `T == U` in provided code though).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can write the specialization so it inherit from the generic version.

By example: suppose you have a `struct foo` with a type and a value (with default value) template parameters; suppose it has some methods (`bar()`, in the following example)

```
template <typename, bool = true>
struct foo 
 { void bar () {}; };
```

and suppose you want a specialization for `bool` (as template type) with the same methods and an additional `baz()`; you can inherit `foo<bool>` from the general version as follows

```
template <>
struct foo<bool> : public foo<bool, false>
 { void baz () {}; };
```

You can verify that

```
   foo<int>   fi;

   fi.bar();   // compile
   //fi.baz(); // compilation error

   foo<bool>  fb;

   fb.bar();  // compile
   fb.baz();  // compile
```

Comment: This is great and I will keep it in mind, but @Jarod42 answer is more elegant i think. Still, thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a question through - what does the `bool = true` do in the template specification?

Comment: @KONAKONA - Oh yes: the Jarod42's solution is a very good one. The `bool = true` declare a second template parameter, a value of type `bool`, with a default value (`true`); so when you define `foo<bool>`, you're defining `foo<bool, true>`. I use the second template parameter to inherit from the generic version mantaining the same type (`bool`) for the first template parameter.

Comment: Btw, before C++20, I prefer a variant of this one: `template <typename T>
struct foo : foo_baz<T> {/*..*/};` with empty `foo_baz<T>` and a specialization for `foo_baz<bool>`.